# SQLAlchemy - order_by on relationship for join table

Tags: python, sql, model, sqlalchemy, declarative

I'm using declarative SQLAlchemy and I have three models:  `Role`, `Permission`, and `RolePermission`.  In my `Role` model, I have the following:

```
class Role(Base):
    name = Column(u'NAME', VARCHAR(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    permissionLinks = relationship(RolePermission, backref="role", order_by=name)
    permissions = relationship(Permission, backref=backref("roles",
      order_by=name), secondary=RolePermission.__table__,
      order_by=Permission.name)
```

Now the `permissions` declaration works fine, and the permissions associated with a role come out sorted as I expect (by name).  However, `permissionLinks` fails with the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "ROLES.NAME" could not be bound. (4104) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)') u'SELECT [ROLES_PERMISSIONS].[ROLE_ID] AS [ROLES_PERMISSIONS_ROLE_ID], [ROLES_PERMISSIONS].[PERMISSION_ID] AS [ROLES_PERMISSIONS_PERMISSION_ID], [ROLES_PERMISSIONS].[IS_DENIED] AS [ROLES_PERMISSIONS_IS_DENIED] \nFROM [ROLES_PERMISSIONS] \nWHERE [ROLES_PERMISSIONS].[ROLE_ID] = ? ORDER BY [ROLES].[NAME]' (19,)

The problem is that `Role` is not being joined, so it can't sort by `Role.name`.  I tried specifying `primaryjoin=id == RolePermission.id1`, but that didn't seem to change anything.  How can I specify a join on this relationship such that I can sort by a field in one of the joined tables (namely, `Role.name`)?

Answer (score 37):

I couldn't make any of these solutions work, however I found an easier way.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class User(Base):
    # ....
    addresses = relationship("Address",
                         order_by="desc(Address.email)",
                         primaryjoin="Address.user_id==User.id")
```

Found here:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/relationships.html

Comment: Haha! Ran in to this problem and found your answer! Yours is the only one that works!

Answer (score 8):

What you want is to order the role attribute of the RolePermission object. Passing order_by sets the order in the Role class.

Try this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref

permissionLinks = relationship(RolePermission, backref=backref("role", order_by=name))
```

setting an order for the back reference

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `permissionLinks` relationship. Ordering its items by by `Role.name` makes no sense to me.

Comment: I want to display all the `RolePermission` rows associated with a given permission, and I want them displayed in order of `Role.name`.  Currently I sort them after getting the results from the DB, but it seems I should be able to do that with SQLAlchemy.  I display the `RolePermission` rows and not just `Permission` rows (via `permissions`) because `RolePermission` has info about creation date, creator, etc. that `Permission` does not have.

Comment: But in your sample code you are trying to sort `RolePermission` objects associated with given _role_.

Comment: Right.  It seems like that should be doable, because each `RolePermission` has a `Role`, so why can't I sort `RolePermission`s by a property on `Role`?